# Monitoring a cron running on HPCC cluster

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I have a cron scheduled to run on Thor cluster. Is there a way to monitor a cron running on HPCC Cluster and send a notification if the cron is not running due to a failure or system shutdown?

Comment: What's a "CRON"?

Comment: A "CRON" (derived from chronometer) job is a workunit that instigates its action on a periodic basis, typically at the same time every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akhilesh,

The only way I can think of to do that would be to make the CRON job periodically send a "ping" of some sort (an email, or update a semaphore file, or ... ) then have a separate process running on another box to alert someone if that "ping" doesn't arrive as scheduled (indicating the CRON job is no longer working).

HTH,

Richard

Comment: Fine Richard. Thank you for the help.